# How to join 2 tables with no common key in the most simplest way?

Tags: python, sql

This is the database i created:

```
students = [('TOM', 6120, 85),
           ('Jerry', 6110,86),
           ('Spike', 6120,55),
           ('Tyke',6110,73),
           ('Butch',6110,89),
           ('Toodle',6120,76)]
courses = [(6110,'Data Science I', 'LSB105'),
          (6120,'Data Science II', 'LSB109')]
grading = [('A', 90, 100),
          ('B', 80,90),
          ('C',70,80)]

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example3.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE students(name TEXT, courseid INTEGER, score INTEGER)') #create a table
c.executemany('INSERT INTO students VALUES(?,?,?)', students)

c.execute('CREATE TABLE courses(courseid INTEGER, name TEXT, classroom TEXT)') #create a table
c.executemany('INSERT INTO courses VALUES(?,?,?)', courses)

c.execute('CREATE TABLE gradingscheme(letter TEXT, lower REAL, upper REAL)') #create a table
c.executemany('INSERT INTO gradingscheme VALUES(?,?,?)', grading)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

That's what i want in the end:
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuHbT.png)

I did it by 3 steps and i think my method is too complicated:

```
c.execute('''
CREATE view part1 AS
SELECT s.name,s.courseid,c.name AS coursename,classroom,score
FROM students AS s, courses AS c
WHERE s.courseid=c.courseid 
''')

#Create another view "part2" to combine "part1" and table: "gradingscheme"
c.execute('''
CREATE view part2 AS
SELECT * FROM part1 , (SELECT * FROM gradingscheme AS g)
''')

#Get the final results
c.execute('''
SELECT name, courseid, coursename, classroom, score, letter
FROM part2 
WHERE score BETWEEN lower AND upper
''')
```

So, can anyone help me shorten my code? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Views are not needed in this case. You can join directly as follows. I have used left join for gradingscheme to handle the scores that are not in the range defined in gradingscheme. For example, I used grade 'D' for scores less than 70. If you dont need it and all ranges will be given in gradingscheme table, you can use JOIN itself instead of LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT s.name, s.courseid, 
c.name AS coursename, 
c.classroom, s.score, 
COALESCE(g.letter, 'D') AS grade
FROM students s
JOIN courses c
ON (s.courseid=c.courseid)
LEFT JOIN gradingscheme g
ON (s.score >= g.lower AND s.score <= g.upper)
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put put your JOINs into views, or split them up into multiple views that each join two tables. The following should produce the same result as your latter snippet:

```
SELECT s.name, s.courseid, c.name AS coursename, c.classroom, s.score, g.letter
FROM students AS s, courses AS c, gradingscheme AS g
WHERE s.courseid=c.courseid
AND s.score BETWEEN g.lower AND g.upper
```